# LINQ query with Distinct and Union 

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I currently have 2 queries that are returning lists of MyModel like this:

```
var q1 = ....
         select new MyModel()
         {
             TheData1 = ...
             TheData2 = ...
             TheUniqueID = ...
         }

var q2 = ....
         select new MyModel()
         {
             TheData1 = ...
             TheData2 = ...
             TheUniqueID = ...
         }
```

If in q1 I have:

```
TheUniqueID = 2,3,6,9,11
```

and in q2 I have:

```
TheUniqueID = 2,4,7,9,12
```

How do write the query so that I get a list of MyModel where

```
TheUniqueID = 2,3,4,6,7,9,11,12
```

In other words, each TheUniqueID is present only once (ie. 2 and 9 not repeated).

I started looking at Union and distinct but I'm wondering if I need 2 from statements or not.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Is this LINQ to Objects or LINQ to SQL etc?

Comment: it's a linq to sql query

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think frenchie wants a list of `MyModel` back instead of just the `TheUniqueID`.

You need to create a `MyModelTheUniqueIDComparer` class and pass a new instance of it as a second argument into `Union`:

```
class MyModelTheUniqueIDComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyModel>
{
    public bool Equals(MyModel x, MyModel y)
    {
        return x.TheUniqueID == y.TheUniqueID;
    }

    // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects 
    // then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects.

    public int GetHashCode(MyModel myModel)
    {
        return myModel.TheUniqueID.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then you can call to get the result:

```
var result = q1.Union(q2, new MyModelTheUniqueIDComparer());
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358407.aspx for a more details.

**Update:**

Try this:

```
public class A
{
    public string TheData1 { get; set; }
    public string TheData2 { get; set; }
    public string UniqueID { get; set; }
}

public class AComparer : IEqualityComparer<A>
{

    #region IEqualityComparer<A> Members

    public bool Equals(A x, A y)
    {
        return x.UniqueID == y.UniqueID;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(A obj)
    {
        return obj.UniqueID.GetHashCode();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And test with this:

```
var listOfA = new List<A>();
var q1 = from a in listOfA
                 select new A()
             {
                 TheData1 = "TestData",
                 TheData2 = "TestData",
                 UniqueID = a.UniqueID
             };

var anotherListOfA = new List<A>();
var q2 = from a in anotherListOfA
                 select new A()
                 {
                     TheData1 = "TestData",
                     TheData2 = "TestData",
                     UniqueID = a.UniqueID
                 };

q1.Union(q2, new AComparer());
```

Make sure you have `using System.Linq;`

Comment: ah! I kind of knew it wasn't going to be something simple! I'm taking a break and I'll be back to try this out in a bit. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I get an unsupported overload used for query operator Union error. I'm trying to cast but it's not working: return result as List<MyModel> or return (List<MyModel>)result doesn't work on the return statement. Any idea why?

Comment: try
`return q1.Union(q2, new MyModelTheUniqueIDComparer()).ToList();`

Comment: +1, this is also great if you have no unique values in your object, but the combination of the objects is unique - so for example in Equals:
`return (x.TheData1.equals(y.TheData1)) && (x.TheData2.equals(y.TheData2))` and for GetHashCode: `return (obj.TheData1 + obj.TheData2).GetHashCode()`. Obviously in this case you wouldn't need that due to UniqueID, but it's useful in other situations where there is no equivalent.

Answer (score 13):

[`Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx) creates an Enumerable with unique values from both collections.  In other words, you don't need `Distinct`.

edit: example of Union [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336761.aspx#union1)

edit2: forgot that it's not the list of `UniqueIDs` that you're concatenating. I removed the suggested code since it was wrong. You should be able to do a simple `Union` if you implement an [`IEqualityComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx), but that might be overkill.

Answer (score 6):

As was pointed out if you are combining the lists with `.Union(`) you will have to define uniqueness by using the overload passing an [IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) for your type.

```
var result = q1.Union(q2, myEqualityComparer);
```

otherwise, and easier you could use `DistinctBy( x=> x.TheUniqueId)` from the [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs) project:

```
var result = q1.Concat(q2).DistinctBy(c => c.TheUniqueID);
```

Comment: `MoreLinq` seems to have become a dead link. Try this instead: https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/

Answer (score 4):

**Inefficient single line answer with no IEqualityComparerer**

Using MoreLinq source code as inspiration, this will give a unique list:

Short answer (the OrderBy isn't necessary but if not used the answer comes out as 2,3,6,9,11,4,7,12):

```
var concattedUniqueList = theUniqueIDList1.Concat(theUniqueIDList2)
            .GroupBy(f=>f.UniqueID, f=>f).Select(g => g.First()).OrderBy(f=>f.UniqueID);
```

Complete answer:

```
//INPUT
//theUniqueIDList1 = 2,3,6,9,11 
//theUniqueIDList2 = 2,4,7,9,12
//OUTPUT
//2,3,4,6,7,9,11,12
public class MyModel
{
    public string TheData1 { get; set; }
    public string TheData2 { get; set; }
    public int UniqueID { get; set; }
}

public static void GroupByEx1()
    {
        // Create a list of Models.
        List<MyModel> theUniqueIDList1 =
            new List<MyModel>{  new MyModel { TheData1="Barley",    UniqueID=2 },
                                    new MyModel { TheData1="Boots",     UniqueID=3 },
                                    new MyModel { TheData1="Whiskers",  UniqueID=6 },
                                    new MyModel { TheData1="Daisy",     UniqueID=9 },
                                    new MyModel { TheData1="Preti",     UniqueID=11 } };
        List<MyModel> theUniqueIDList2 =
            new List<MyModel>{  new MyModel { TheData1="Barley",    UniqueID=2 },
                                    new MyModel { TheData1="Henry",     UniqueID=4 },
                                    new MyModel { TheData1="Walsh",     UniqueID=7 },
                                    new MyModel { TheData1="Daisy",     UniqueID=9 },
                                    new MyModel { TheData1="Ugly",  UniqueID=12 } };
        
        var concattedUniqueList = theUniqueIDList1.Concat(theUniqueIDList2)
            .OrderBy(f=>f.UniqueID).GroupBy(f=>f.UniqueID, f=>f).Select(g => g.First());

        foreach (var item in concattedUniqueList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("UniqueId: {0}({1})", item.UniqueID, item.TheData1);
        }
    }
    
void Main()
{
    GroupByEx1();               
    //2,3,4,6,7,9,11,12
}
```

Note: compared to using an IEqualityComparer for speed - 10000 times for each
698 ns for Concat
100 ns for IEqualityComparer

## developed in [LinqPad](http://www.LinqPad.net)

Comment: In my opinion this is the best answer. It's way better than making your own comparer. To be fussy I would do `.GroupBy(f=>f.UniqueID, f=>f).SelectMany(g => g.Take(1));` as a way of habitually not calling `.First()`. It works here, but in other queries calling `.First()` can lead to issues. But certainly still the best answer.

Comment: What if two list are of different types but the parameter UniqueID is same in both lists ?