# LINQ Union not going into overridden Equals method

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to remove duplicates when merging two lists of objects (vehicles) using `LINQ` like:

```
var list = list1.Union(list2);
```

I have `overridden the Equal`s method and the code wont even step into it.  However, this code does step into the override:

```
Vehicle v1 = new Vehicle();
Vehicle v2 = new Vehicle();

if (v1.Equals(v2)).......
```

EDIT

The signatures for the Vehicle overrides are here:

I also implement `IEquatable<Vehicle>`

```
 public bool Equals(Vehicle other)
 {                     
 }

 public override int GetHashCode()
 {            
 }
```

I would rather not pass a comparer to the Union method as I want thelogic in the Vehicle class.

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: you need to implement `getHashCode` also http://stackoverflow.com/a/5276417/1714342

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ query with Distinct and Union](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276169/linq-query-with-distinct-and-union)

Comment: I have done this also - I'll update in case it's wrong

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have nothing to do with `IEquatable<Vehicle>`, it's just an option but not a required `must-do`. I think you didn't override your `Equals` correctly, it should look like this:

```
 public override bool Equals(object other) {                     
   //your own code
 }

 public override int GetHashCode() {            
   //your own code
 }
```

**NOTE** the keyword **override** and the argument of type `object` which matches the *virtual* `Equals` method of base object.

Comment: For me it was unnecessarily inheriting `IEqualityComparer<>`.