# How to take union of an array by using operator overloading?

Tags: c#, arrays

I take a class  Set A class that will keep an array in the constructor of class we initialize the array and make two objects of that array and like

I need that at + operator the union of two array should come 
guide me .and at operator parameter a and b it is giving error also

```
public class seta
{
public seta(int size)

{
    this.size = Size;
    int[] array = new int[size]



}

private int size;

public int Size
{
    get { return size; }
    set { size = value; }
}


 Console.WriteLine ("enter  size of an array   aray");`
`
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            seta obja = new seta(a);

            Console.WriteLine("enter  size of an array   aray");
            int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            seta objb = new seta(b);
        }

            public static double operator + (  a , b )
        {
        }
```

Comment: Please tell us what error you are getting, and why you are implementing this yourself instead of using the [built-in `union` method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276169/).

Comment: I wanna to do it by operator overloading i wanna to overload the operator + here but getting error at    
            public static double operator + (  a , b )
        Parameter here

Comment: What are the elements of the array? `int`, `string`, `double` ? Please include the basic skeleton of `seta` class.

Comment: public class seta
    {
    public seta(int size)

    {
        this.size = Size;
          
        

    }

    private int size;

    public int Size
    {
        get { return size; }
        set { size = value; }
    }
herer this is class that i made

Comment: Not in the comments. Edit the question and add it there. Again, what types does the array hold? Is it an array of what? I don't see any array or collection definitions in `seta`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will create two random arrays stored in `class SetA { }` and then find the union with the `operator +`. Under the hood it just calls `Enumerable.Union()`

```
public class SetA
{
    static Random rng = new Random();
    int[] data;
    public SetA(int[] data)
    {
        this.data=data;
    }
    public SetA(int size)
    {
        this.data=new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i<data.Length; i++)
        {
            data[i]=rng.Next(0, 100);
        }
    }
    public int Size { get { return data.Length; } }
    public int[] Data { get { return data; } }
    public static SetA operator +(SetA a, SetA b)
    {
        return new SetA(a.data.Union(b.data).ToArray());
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SetA a = new SetA(100);
        SetA b = new SetA(50);

        SetA c = a+b;
        int n = c.Size;
    }
}
```